# What is standard CLR XML for a concrete generic that is an array?

Tags: .net, xml, syntax

This is a simple issue of me not knowing proper Xml syntax.  In castle windsor I can duplicate this line of code:

```
IoC.Container.AddComponent<IInputRequestedDialog<string>, SealsInputDialog>("seals");
```

With this Xml:

```
<component id="seals" 
    service="MyApp.InputRequestedDialog`1[[System.String]], MyApp" 
    type="MyApp.SealsInputDialog, MyApp" />
```

But what if the concrete generic is a string array rather than  a string?  How do I xml-ize the following?

```
IoC.Container.AddComponent<IInputRequestedDialog<string[]>, SealsInputDialog>("seals");
```

Answer (score 2):

Quoting Ken Egozi from [the Castle Project Mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-devel/browse_thread/thread/ab3eb5bd01383bc1):

---

I just did

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof (IFoo<string[]>).FullName);
```

the output was:

> IFoo`1[[System.String[], mscorlib,
>   Version=2.0.0.0  , Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]

so I guess

```
 service="MyApp.InputRequestedDialog`1[System.String[] ], MyApp"
```

should be working, 
and if not,

```
 service="MyApp.InputRequestedDialog`1[[System.String[], mscorlib, Version= 
2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], MyApp"
```

---

System.String[] works great, and I learned something about how to find out the proper Xml representation of a type too!

Comment: Upvoting an answer that quotes me feel strange :)